# mongodb after updating document, returns old values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, es6-promise

```
router.delete('/deletepost', (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.query.postid)
    if (req.query.category === 'forsale') {
        ForSalePosts.findById(req.query.postid)
            // .then(post => console.log(post))
            .deleteOne()
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

        AllPosts.updateOne({ user: req.query.userid },
            { $pull: { posts: { postid: req.query.postid } } })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            AllPosts.aggregate(
                [

                    { $match: { user: ObjectId(req.query.userid) } },
                    { $unwind: '$posts' },
                    { $sort: { 'posts.date': -1 } }

                ]
            )
                .then(posts => {
                    // console.log(posts)
                    res.json(posts)
                })
                .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nopostfound: 'There is no posts' }))

    }
})
```

this is my route. i am trying to delete an item in my document. the item is being deleted however it returns old values. for example :

Allposts has an array with posts:[postid:{type:String}, ...]
I am trying to delete a specific postid by using $pull,
postid is being deleted however when I aggregate the same model, .then(posts=> console.log(posts)) returns old values on first call, doesnt update the component.

EDIT: just realized sometimes it returns the right values but sometimes it returns the old values as well. does anyone know why and what can i do to solve it ?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AllPostsSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    posts: [{
        postid: {
            type: String
        },
        title: {
            type: String
        },
        category: {
            type: String
        },
        subcategory: {
            type: String
        }, category: {
            type: String
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        price: {
            type: Number
        },
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: Number
        },
        language: {
            type: String
        },
        make: {
            type: String
        },
        model: {
            type: Number
        },
        odometer: {
            type: Number
        },
        condition: {
            type: String
        },
        state: {
            type: String
        },
        town: {
            type: String
        },
        city: {
            type: String
        },
        links: [{ type: String }],

        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }]

})


module.exports = AllPosts = mongoose.model('allposts', AllPostsSchema)
```

REACT FUNCTION CALL :

```
  deletePost = (category, postid) => {
        const postinfo = {
            category: category.toLowerCase(),
            postid: postid,
            userid: this.props.auth.user.id
        }

        this.props.deletePost(postinfo)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the mongo queries return partial promise. You have to use `.then` in order to resolve each promises.

Here you are running all the queries in series without using `.then` or `async-await`. So whenever you `$pull` from `AllPosts` after that immediately you call the `AllPosts` aggregate query which sometimes get executed and sometimes it doesn't.

So in order to make it run one by one you have to use either `.then` or `async-await`.

```
router.delete("/deletepost", (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.category === "forsale") {
    ForSalePosts.findById(req.query.postid)
      .deleteOne()
      .then(() => {
        AllPosts.updateOne(
          { "user": req.query.userid },
          { "$pull": { "posts": { "postid": req.query.postid } } }
        )
          .then(() => {
            AllPosts.aggregate([
              { "$match": { "user": ObjectId(req.query.userid) } },
              { "$unwind": "$posts" },
              { "$sort": { "posts.date": -1 } }
            ]).then(posts => {
              // console.log(posts)
              res.json(posts);
            });
          })
          .catch(err =>
            res.status(404).json({ "nopostfound": "There is no posts" })
          );
      });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `options` parameter to `delete` like:

```
AllPosts.updateOne({ user: req.query.userid }, 
    { 
     $pull: { posts: { postid: req.query.postid } } 
    }, 
    { new: true }
);
```

This will return the new object after performing the operation. Hope this works for you.